# Force a compile time error if std::move will result in an unintended copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In his GoingNative 2013 talk, Scott Meyers pointed out that `std::move` is no guarantee that the generated code will actually perform a move.

Example:

```
void foo(std::string x, const std::string y) {
  std::string x2 = std::move(x); // OK, will be moved
  std::string y2 = std::move(y); // compiles, but will be copied
}
```

Here, the move constructor cannot be applied but because of overload resolution, the normal copy constructor will be used instead. This fallback option may be crucial for backward compatibility with C++98 code, but in the example above it is most likely not what the programmer intended.

**Is there a way to enforce that a move constructor will be called?**

For example, assume that you want to move a huge matrix. If your application really depend on the Matrix to be moved, it would be great to immediately get a compile error if a move is not possible. (Otherwise, you the performance problem may slip easily through unit tests and you will only find out after some profiling.)

Lets call this guaranteed move `strict_move`. I would like to be able to write code like this:

```
void bar(Matrix x, const Matrix y) {
  Matrix x2 = strict_move(x); // OK
  Matrix y2 = strict_move(y); // compile error
}
```

Is it possible?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the great answers! There were some legitimate requests to clarify my question:

- Should `strict_move` fail if the input is const?
- Should `strict_move` fail if the result will not lead to an actual move operation (even though the copy might be as fast as a move, e.g., `const complex<double>`)?
- Both?

My original idea was very vague: I considered Scott Meyers examples quite alarming, so I wondered if it is possible to have the compiler prevent such unintended copies.

Scott Meyers mentioned in his talk that a general compiler warning is not an option as it would result in a huge number a false positives. Instead I want to communicate to the compiler something like "I'm 100% sure that this must always resulting in a move operation and a copy is too expensive for this specific type".

Thus, I would have offhandedly said that `strict_move` should fail in both cases. Meanwhile I'm not sure what would be best. Another aspects that I didn't consider is `noexcept`.

From my side, the exact semantics of `strict_move` are open. Everything that helps to prevent some dumb mistakes at compile time without having serious drawbacks is fine.

Comment: Make your own version of `move` that checks the return type?

Comment: Wait, did you want to check that the input isn't const, or did you want to check that an actual move will happen.  Because the second is a bad idea, and the answers below ignore that interpretation.

Comment: @MooingDuck Interesting, I haven't thought about that difference in detail, I just wanted to have a safety net against unintentional behavior. I agree that preventing moving `const` object is safer, but what are the arguments against additionally checking that a move constructor is available and would be called? I can understand that using such a construct in library code could make the code inflexible as it excludes all classes without move constructors and might cause problems with conversions. But what are the downside of using it only in a performance critical part of your own code base?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen: Because it would make the code inflexible as it excludes all classes without move constructors and might cause problems with conversions.

Comment: If you concern is mainly about the problem of copying a huge matrix (that your class matrix holds), then using strict_move does not solve your problem completely. (if you try to move std::vector<matrix>  and your matrix move constructor can throw an exception, than compiler will actually copy the vector elements). See my answer for more details

Comment: If you are really concerned about a matrix being copied, how about having the copy constructor declared explicit?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I advise against writing a general `strict_move` that is detecting `const`.  I think that is not really what you're looking for.  Do you want this to flag a `const complex<double>`, or a const `pair<int, int>`?  These types will copy as fast they move.  Flagging them would just be an irritant.

If you want to do this, I recommend instead checking to see if the type is `noexcept MoveConstructible`.  This will work perfectly for `std::string`.  If the copy constructor of `string` is accidentally called, it is not noexcept, and therefore will be flagged.  But if the copy constructor of `pair<int, int>` is accidentally called, do you really care?

Here is a sketch of what this would look like:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&
noexcept_move(T&& t)
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type Tr;
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Tr>::value,
                  "noexcept_move requires T to be noexcept move constructible");
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<Tr>::value,
                  "noexcept_move requires T to be noexcept move assignable");
    return std::move(t);
}
```

I decided to check against `is_nothrow_move_assignable` as well, as you don't know whether the client is constructing or assigning the lhs.

I opted for internal `static_assert` instead of an external `enable_if` because I don't expect `noexcept_move` to be overloaded, and the `static_assert` will yield a clearer error message when triggered.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be caring overmuch about forcing a move to _happen_ (that would be a dupe anyway), so much as accidentally using `move` in a way that makes no sense at all.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question.  But my `noexcept_move` behaves as I believe the OP desires with the OP's `foo`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP intended actually.  I upvoted anyway.

Answer (score 6):

First I would like to state that you previous answers will not solve your problem completely.

Counterexample where previous solutions (@Kerrerk and @0x499602D2)  fail: assume that you wrote your matrix class with a move constructor that throws an exception. Now assume that you want to move `std::vector<matrix>`. [This article](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2855.html) shows that you can't have the "strong exception guarantee" if the matrix class elements that the `std::vector<matrix>` holds were actually moved (what happen if the jth element move constructor throws an exception ? You would lose data because there is no way to recover the elements you have already moved!).

That is why stl containers implement `.push_back()`, `.reserve()` and their move constructor using `std::move_if_noexcept` to move the elements they hold. Here is an example implementation of reserve() taken from [open-std](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2983.html) :

```
void reserve(size_type n)
{
    if (n > this->capacity())
    {
        pointer new_begin = this->allocate( n );
        size_type s = this->size(), i = 0;
        try
        {
            for (;i < s; ++i)
                 new ((void*)(new_begin + i)) value_type( std::move_if_noexcept( (*this)[i]) ) );
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            while (i > 0)                 // clean up new elements
               (new_begin + --i)->~value_type();

            this->deallocate( new_begin );    // release storage
            throw;
        }
        // -------- irreversible mutation starts here -----------
        this->deallocate( this->begin_ );
        this->begin_ = new_begin;
        this->end_ = new_begin + s;
        this->cap_ = new_begin + n;
    }
}
```

So, if you don't enforce that your move and default constructor is noexcept, you won't guarantee that functions like std::vector.resize() or std::move (for stl containers) will never copy the matrix class and that is the correct behavior (otherwise you may lose data)

Comment: Claim: while I was writing/reviewing this solution: @HowardHinnant publish a similar answer

Comment: +1 for the references to committee papers.  That's the place to go for rationale.

Answer (score 5):

You can just make your own version of `move` that doesn't allow constant return types. For example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename T>
struct enforce_nonconst
{
    static_assert(!std::is_const<T>::value, "Trying an impossible move");
    typedef typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<T>::value, T>::type type;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr typename enforce_nonconst<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type &&
mymove(T && t) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &&>(t);
}

void foo(std::string a, std::string const b)
{
    std::string x = std::move(a);
    std::string y = std::move(b);
}

void bar(std::string a, std::string const b)
{
    std::string x = mymove(a);
    // std::string y = mymove(b);  // Error
}

int main() { }
```