# What is the exception safety guarantee of vector::insert?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering, exactly what is the exception safety guarantee for `std::vector::insert`? I am interested in both the single-argument and the range overloads of this function.

Comment: This greatly depends on the type being stored in the container

Comment: @David: You are correct. I am interested in the case where it does not have a nothrow move- e.g. only throwing copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact guarantee is given in C++11 23.3.6.5:

> If an exception is thrown other than by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of `T` or by any `InputIterator` operation there are no effects. If an exception is thrown by the move constructor of a non-`CopyInsertable` `T`, the effects are unspecified.

Comment: What does this mean with `there are no effects`? What happens to already assigned elements in the vector?

Comment: @RedX: It means that there are no effects; everything is restored to the initial state, as if nothing happened. If there are already assigned elements, then the exception must have been thrown by "the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of `T` or by any `InputIterator` operation", in which case there's no such guarantee.

Comment: So does this imply basic guarantee for if the copy constructor of T throws?

Comment: @DeadMG: I guess so. Your interpretation is probably as good as mine.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the single-element form of `insert` has a strong exception guarantee for any container as per [container.requirements.general]/10, but `vector::insert` is an exception to this rule:

[vector.modifiers]/1 applies to `vector::insert`; `InputIterator` here refers to the overload of `insert` that inserts a range.

> If an exception is thrown other than by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of `T` or by any `InputIterator` operation there are no effects. If an exception is thrown by the move-constructor of a non-`CopyInsertable` `T`, the effects are unspecified.

---

`vector` is an allocator-aware container, which means that it uses an allocator for memory allocation *and* construction of its elements [container.requirements.general]/3

> For the components affected by this subclause that declare an `allocator_type`, objects stored in these components shall be constructed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct` function and destroyed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy` function. These functions are called only for the container's element type, not for internal types used by the container.

I think this implies that local objects, which are not elements of the container, can be created without using the allocator (e.g. for copy-and-swap). Otherwise, the requirements on the ctors of the value type would be pointless; the allocator's `construct` function might have different exception guarantees than the value type's ctor.

---

`CopyInsertable` is specified in [container.requirements.general]/13 by requiring that

```
allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);
```

is well-formed; where `A` is the allocator type, `m` is of type `A`, `p` is a pointer to `T`, `v` is an expression of type (`const`) `T`, and `T` is the value type of the container. This is an inplace construction from one argument (copy- or move-construction).

Similarly, `MoveConstructible` is specified, but `v` is (always) an rvalue of type `T`. `EmplaceConstructible` follows the same form for zero or more arguments instead of `v`.

The `insert` function for sequence containers imposes different requirements on the value type for its various forms [sequence.reqmts]; here including additional requirements for `vector`:

- for a single argument that is an lvalue of type (`const`) `T` and for the form *insert N copies of*, `T` shall be `CopyInsertable` and `CopyAssignable`
- for a single argument that is an rvalue of type `T`, `T` shall be `MoveInsertable` and `MoveAssignable`
- for the range form, `T` shall be `EmplaceConstructible` from the dereferenced iterators (*); additionally, `MoveInsertable` and `MoveAssignable` if the iterators of the range are no forward iterators

(*) Note: `EmplaceConstructible` only from the dereferenced iterators is not enough if the container has to be resized for the insertion (and, e.g. the `*i` for such an iterator is not of the value type). It is possible that the specification requires the range form to inherit the requirements of the single-element form, i.e. either `MoveAssignable` or `CopyAssignable`.

*Side remark:* The range form of `insert` requires that the two iterators do not point in the container in which they are to be inserted.

---

I interpret the exception specifications as follows:

The additional statement about `CopyInsertable` in the exception specification of `vector::insert` probably distinguishes between the basic guarantee and no guarantee: The dtor of a container is generally required to call the dtor of all elements and deallocate all memory (in the general container requirements). That is, unless the behaviour is unspecified/undefined, the basic guarantee holds.

Why there is a requirement that combines `CopyInsertable` and the move-ctor (instead of `allocator::construct` with an rvalue), I don't know. The move-ctor is only used directly for objects that are not elements of the container (indirectly possibly via `allocator::construct`).

The other remarks about "no effects" (-> strong guarantee) are *not* applied to the allocator operations (`construct`). The allocator operations obviously do not have to be noexcept. As you can provide a non-default allocator that doesn't use the value type's copy- and move-ctor for `construct`, `insert` has to provide the strong exception guarantees even for the `construct` allocator operations. For example, if the allocator's `construct` is not noexcept, during a resize, the elements cannot be move-constructed but have to be copied.

Move- and copy-assignment have to be noexcept for the strong guarantee as the elements might need to be shifted around for `insert`; copy- and move-ctor might need to be noexcept for the strong guarantee because of local objects created in the algorithm.

Comment: Regarding your side remark: what do you do if you *do* want to insert some elements of the container inside itself?

Comment: @Mehrdad Use the single-element form? At least, [it's required to work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18788780/420683).

Answer (score 1):

If the [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) method inserts a single element at the end of the list and does not require any memory to be allocated, offers a strong exception guarantee.

If it has to add more than one element, or has to allocate memory it offers a basic exception guarantee.  [Boost](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html) has a good description of the exception guarantees.

> The basic guarantee: that the invariants of the component are preserved, and no resources are leaked.
>       The strong guarantee: that the operation has either completed successfully or thrown an exception, leaving the program state exactly as it was before the operation started.
>       The no-throw guarantee: that the operation will not throw an exception.

This means that after an exception, you know that the `vector` will be usable, but it may not have all of the data you had inserted in it.  All of the objects that were successfully inserted will be fully constructed.