Does std::vector::assign have the strong exception safety gurantee?
I'm trying to understand the exception safety of the following C++ code:
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::array<int, 500> b{};
    v.assign(b.begin(), b.end());
}

In this code, I'm assigning the elements from a std::array to a std::vector. I looked through cppreference documentation for std::vector::assign, but I couldn't find specific details regarding which exceptions can be thrown during this operation or what exception gurantee provides.
My concerns:

Memory Allocation: I know that if std::vector needs to grow in size, it may have to allocate new memory. This can potentially throw a std::bad_alloc exception.

Partial Assignments: If an exception occurs after some elements from the std::array have been copied to std::vector, it seems like a could end up in an inconsistent state, which violates the strong exception safety guarantee. but in this case int is noexcept copyable since it is trivial type.


Given my understanding, can someone tell me whether the line a.assign(b.begin(), b.end()) is considered exception safe?
I even tried to look into one of the standard library's implementation to check whether it is or not but I couldn't determine.

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532448/what-is-the-exception-safety-guarantee-of-vectorinsert or is even a dupe.

@3CxEZiVlQ I am talking about std::vector::assign not std::vector::insert can you explain to me how are they related? is it because assign is explained interms of clear() then a  call to insert(args...)?

If an exception occurres during elementwise construction or assignment, the only logically feasible approach is to have capacity [[probably]] increased, while the size reflects last good constructor. The only exception guarantee therefore is that the vector is still in good shape, but not equivalent to the input nor initial state.

@Red.Wave: The "strong guarantee" is not an exact specification. In particular, it does not imply a bit-exact state guarantee. capacity may increase, but it's a minimum. The strong guarantee is that capacity is at least the size of the last .reserve or .resize, and that minimum still holds after such a failed assign.

@3CxEZiVlQ insert is a modifier, for which some exception guarantees are specified in vector.modifiers/2. These do not apply for assign.

did you try to test this?

https://godbolt.org/z/1sqdWWMP7 so answer is no.

I guess reserve + std::copy has become the most pervasive method method of dealing with vector initialization. So the assign method has lost its significance; there's no update on terms except for the addition of assign_range with minimal assumed constraints. Logically the 2 functions must have similar behavior.

Attempted Simplification
At first I thought we could break this down a little bit, into two pieces, one for the allocation, and one for the assignment part, by calling reserve before calling assign:
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::array<int, 500> b{};

    v.reserve(b.size());

    v.assign(b.begin(), b.end()); 
}

My hope was to be able to say: "we can all agree that the reserve call can throw, so that leaves only the assignment part.
Unfortunately, I don't think that works. The disclosure in [sequence.reqmts]/57-59 makes it clear that the expectation is that a.assign(b.begin(), b.end()); is intended to be roughly equivalent to:
std::vector<int> temp(b.begin(), b.en());
a = temp;

...so it always allocates space, even if it already has the capacity to hold the assigned range.
Unfortunately, [sequence.reqmts] doesn't have a Throws clause, and neither does [vector.overview].
That leaves only the extremely general description in [res.on.exception.handling]/4:

Functions defined in the C++ standard library that do not have a Throws: paragraph but do have a potentially-
throwing exception specification may throw implementation-defined exceptions.168 Implementations should
report errors by throwing exceptions of or derived from the standard exception classes (17.6.4.1, 17.9, 19.2).



In particular, they can report a failure to allocate storage by throwing an exception of type bad_alloc, or a class derived
from bad_alloc (17.6.4.1).


So, the official answer is that there's nothing in the standard to prevent it from throwing an exception.
I think you've already figured out that from a practical viewpoint, it's difficult to conceive of a way that copying ints from one block of memory to another would throw--but I'm afraid there's nothing in the standard that goes into the level of detail about this case to say it can only throw an exception if the allocation fails (even though footnote 168 certainly hints at that being the situation that would throw an exception).
Summary
I think you're left with the rather unsatisfying answer that if the allocation succeeds, there's almost no chance that an exception will be thrown while copying--but there seems to be nothing in the standard to truly guarantee that.

https://godbolt.org/z/1sqdWWMP7

@MarekR: Yes, we all know if the objects in the vector throw when copied, that copying them will throw. The question was specifically and solely about a vector<int>, not a vector<Foo>, even if Foo sometimes acts vaguely like an int.

This is sad, I expected the standard to specify at least something as trivial as this.

@user24551355: I suspect it kind of fell through the cracks. It got classed along with ctors, but then when they dealt with ctors...they dealt only with ctors. So yeah, not great, but somewhat understandable. Most people would rather work on new features than scanning through the document for things like this.
