# emplace_back() issue under VS2013

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-studio-2013

Consider the following codes

```
std::vector<int> nums{21, 22, 23, 24};
nums.emplace_back(nums[0]);
nums.emplace_back(nums[1]);

for (auto n : nums) {
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

Output of `VS2013`

```
21
22
23
24
-17891602
22
```

**Why the `-17891602` is here?**

Output of `GCC 4.8.4`is correct as following

```
21
22
23
24
21
22
```

Then I compare the implementation of `emplace_back` between `VS2013` and `GCC`

VS2013

```
template<class... _Valty>
    void emplace_back(_Valty&&... _Val)
    {   // insert by moving into element at end
    if (this->_Mylast == this->_Myend)
        _Reserve(1);
    _Orphan_range(this->_Mylast, this->_Mylast);
    this->_Getal().construct(this->_Mylast,
        _STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
    ++this->_Mylast;
    }
```

GCC

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
template<typename... _Args>
  void
  vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
  emplace_back(_Args&&... __args)
  {
    if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
      {
        _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                                 std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
        ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
      }
    else
      _M_emplace_back_aux(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
  }
```

It seems the weird `_Reserve(1);` is used in `VS2013`. Why?

Edit:

The `hex` value of `-17891602` is `0xFEEEFEEE`, which means

> Used by Microsoft's debug HeapFree() to mark freed heap memory

refer to [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

Then I debugged the above codes line by line and found the `0XFEEEFEEE` caused by `_Reserve(1);` invoked.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can std::vector emplace_back copy construct from an element of the vector itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908718/can-stdvector-emplace-back-copy-construct-from-an-element-of-the-vector-itself).

Comment: In this question, I want to know why `_Reserve(1)` is used in `VS2013`? different with the link above.

Answer (score 12):

This is a problem in VS2013 and VS2015 when emplacing an element into a vector that contains the element.  If the vector resizes, the reference to the element being inserted is invalid.  The work around is to create a copy of the element in insert, then insert that.

```
auto n = nums[0];
nums.emplace_back(n);
```

The _Reserve call is there to ensure there is some memory allocated for the vector (so it doesn't have to be checked for in later operations).

Comment: It's a workaround for an unfortunate design choice. A similar workaround is `.emplace_back(nums[0]+0)`. Adding 0 shouldn't change the outcome, logically!

Comment: @hvd See the discussion in http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2164. The current wording seems to require this to work.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the reference. It's `nums.emplace_back(std::move(n));` that's not required to work; I missed that since `emplace_back` takes a forwarding reference which becomes an lvalue reference here, the rule that makes this invalid doesn't apply, even though that's specifically mentioned in a note in [res.on.argument]1.3. I've deleted my previous comment. Apparently for a long time, the plan was to formally make it invalid for lvalue references too, according to the link to #760 in there.

Comment: LWG 2164 is about `emplace`, not `emplace_back`. The true difference between these implementations is in the code not shown: what happens in the reallocation case. If the new object construction throws an exception, there must not be any effects. The only way I know to do this is to construct the new object in the new buffer first, and then copy or move the old elements from the old buffer to the new buffer.  If move constructions are not noexcept, copy must be used.  Either VS2013 has figured out another way to do this, or they are always using copy to move the old elements to the new buffer.

Comment: Or perhaps they are not giving the strong exception safety guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

[The emplace issue](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#760)

> Objects bound to the function parameter pack of the `emplace` member function shall **not** be elements or sub-objects of elements of the container.

<strike>The `emplace_back()` is called in the `emplace()` function under `VS2013`.</strike>

```
  template<class... _Valty>
    iterator emplace(const_iterator _Where, _Valty&&... _Val)
    {   // insert by moving _Val at _Where
    size_type _Off = _VIPTR(_Where) - this->_Myfirst;

 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (size() < _Off)
        _DEBUG_ERROR("vector emplace iterator outside range");
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */

    emplace_back(_STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
    _STD rotate(begin() + _Off, end() - 1, end());
    return (begin() + _Off);
    }
```

I found one good [post](http://www.gahcep.com/cpp-internals-stl-vector-part-2/), which describe some details of `emplace_back()` implementation under `VS2013`.

`std::vector` class has different instance members (both regular and internal) and among them are the following:

- `_Myfirst` - points to the beginning of the data array
- `_Mylast` - points to the first uninitialized element in the data array. If equals to _Myend, next insertion will cause reallocation. You get this guy on `end()` call
- `_Myend` - points to the end of the data array

So, in terms of memory addresses, the following inequality takes place:

`_Myfirst <=<= _Mylast <=<= _Myend`

See that line with `_Reserve(1)` in it? This function call causes our bug to reveal itself.

Let's work through step-by-step (refer to previous example function).

```
nums.emplace_back(nums[0]);
```

First we get a **reference** to the item because `operator[]` returns a `reference`

```
reference operator[](size_type _Pos) 
{ ... }
```

Then we move into `emplace_back` method, passing fresh and valid **reference** to the item we want to insert. What we immediately see at the beginning is a check on vector's size exceeding. As long as our insertion causes a vector to grow its size, we get **reference invalidated just after reallocation happens**. That's the reason of such interesting but expected (once we got into implementation) behavior.

Comment: That's a proposed resolution that LWG apparently disagrees with. Besides, that doesn't affect `emplace_back`.