# How can I make this piece of code compile in vs 2015 community?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
vector<set<int> > g_vec;
int main()
{
    g_vec.push_back({ 1 });
    g_vec.push_back({ 1 });
    g_vec.emplace_back(g_vec[0]);//Access violation at address 0xDDDDDDE1
    //g_vec.push_back(g_vec[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile this piece of code on ideone :http://ideone.com/BmYzMR.

But vs2015 gives me an runtime error .(Access violation at address 0xDDDDDDE1)
[image]
[image]

Is this undefined behaviour ?

How can I make my code work on vs2015?

Comment: If you get a runtime error, it must have compiled successfully.

Comment: Looks like an MSVS bug as [it is required to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788780/is-it-safe-to-push-back-an-element-from-the-same-vector)

Comment: @NathanOliver  The example you give is a vector<int>  This is a vector<set<int>>.  He's constructing a set with a single integer as the construction parameter in the line `push_back({1});` [at least I think that's what's happening].

Comment: Yep, MSVC bug. STL once posted on reddit that this is hard to implement, and apparently no one at Microsoft got around to fix it so far.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's `push_back`, `push_back` is working (try it).

Comment: @DaleWilson How does that make any difference?

Comment: @GillBates I know.  I posted that link because in it all functions that insert into the vector must be able to insert an element from the vector into itself.  cc DaleWilson

Comment: @GillBates `emplace_back` should work too.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I think this is this discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/vog1p/a_commonly_unknown_stdvector_pitfall/

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is either post a bug report or find an existing one and make sure it is being worked on.  As a work around you can create a copy and them emplace that back but that is going to have a performance penalty.