# std::move return and input reference argument

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, move-semantics

(A)

```
std::string doNothing(const std::string&& s)
{
  return std::move(s);
}
```

(B)

```
std::string doNothing(const std::string& s)
{
  return std::move(s);
}
```

(Test)

```
const std::string str = "aaaaaa";
const auto str2 = doNothing(str);
```

two questions:

1. are (A) and (B) differetnt?
2. in (Test): will str be undefined? after it is moved to str2?

Comment: Your test case shouldn't compile. an lvalue `str` can't bind to `&&`.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: `str` is `const`, so it cannot be modified. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646874/force-a-compile-time-error-if-stdmove-will-result-in-an-unintended-copy?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

`std::move` takes a (non-const) rvalue reference as an argument.  So you can't bind it directly to a `const` anything, whether rvalue or not.  So in both (A) and (B), when you call `std::move`, it makes an unnamed temporary copy and moves that.

As a result, `str` is never moved from, and is never affected by any of this.

To get rid of the `const` without making a copy, you need an explicit `const_cast`.  If you did that, you'd get the obvious undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

1. they are different. in A case, function accepts *only rvalues* of type const string, it doesn't accept lvalues, since you *can not* bind lvalue to rvalue reference. the function from B case accepts both rvalues and lvalues, since you *can* bind rvalue to const lvalue reference. inside their bodies they are equivalent, unless you are doing decltype (parameter).
2. again, there is std::string( const std::string & ) copy constructor, that can accept rvalue string object (std::move( s ) returns const std::string && and copying occurs).

Answer (score -1):

With the given test code, the cases are different because `A` fails to compile and `B` does compile.

In case `A` an rvalue reference cannot bind to an lvalue.

In case `B` the function returns a copy of the string. Using `std::move` with a const reference still yields a const reference.

Comment: I don't see anything about `A` that would cause it to not compile.  `const std::string&&` is valid. Weird and useless, but valid.

Comment: @MooingDuck An rvalue reference cannot bind to an lvalue. [Link to MCVE](https://godbolt.org/g/8JMtKo)

Comment: Ah, I see the misunderstanding.  `A` compiles fine.  It's the _caller_ that fails to compile. The caller would have to cast the parameter in order to a `const T&&` to call `A`.